# C# foreach against populated list is returning null

Tags: c#, foreach, xamarin.android

Following some major refactoring (moving to a PCL) I have some code (which was not part of the refactor) that was running fine but is now throwing exceptions.

The code is part of a Xamarin Android project which was using File Linking before the move to a Portable Class Library.

It's a simple thing but I can't see why this would happen

```
foreach(var station in stationList)
{

    // Breakpoint on next line shows station to be null..!
    if(station.ClusterId != Guid.Empty)
    {
        // Code in here
    }
}
```

The problem is that although the `stationList` contains a number of `StationViewModel` objects the `station` instance is always null - how can that be?

I have tried replacing the `foreach` with a `for` loop but the result was the same - `station` was null.

I've also restarted Visual Studio and rebooted.

No Xamarin updates appear to be outstanding.

The code was running fine and the generation of the `stationList` has not changed nor has the implementation of this class.

**EDIT**:
The `stationList` creation process is:

1. Call made to SQLite 'repo' in PCL which returns `IList<station>` (which is populated)

   `_loadedStations = await _stationManager.GetStationsAsync();`
2. Using AutoMapper a new `List<StationViewModel>` is generated from the above list (which is populated correctly)

   `fullStationList = AutoMapper.Mapper.Map<IList<Station>, IList<StationViewModel>>(_loadedStations);`
3. In a separate method the view model list above is filtered based on the LatLng coordinates.

   `var stationList = fullStationList.Where(x => mapBounds.Contains(new LatLng(x.Latitude, x.Longitude))).ToList();`

The `foreach` follows the above line of code..

**SOLUTION**:
Well I've 'solved' the problem but still don't know what caused it.

In the same method as the `foreach` there is another, contained within an `if`. It too has the station identifier;

```
if (zoomChanged)
{
    foreach (var station in fullStationList)
    {
        station.ClusterId = Guid.Empty;
    }
    RunOnUiThread(() => _stationMap.Clear());
    _clusters.Clear();
}
```

By changing either of the variable names the code will run fine and the previously erroring loop will run without any problem.

> Note that this 2nd loop was not within the 1st one - that's obviously
>   not going to work, but I can't see why this was causing a problem.

Comment: can you show us the part where stationList is being populated? I doubt that it is populating NULL values in the List.

Comment: I've added some more detail and code as request

Comment: when generating stationlist, try removing all null values from the list, like
var stationList = fullStationList.Where(x => mapBounds.Contains(new LatLng(x.Latitude, x.Longitude))).ToList().RemoveAll(item => item == null);

Comment: @UsamaTariq There are no null items in the stationList, all items are correctly populated StationViewModels

Comment: What are the counts of Items in _loadedStations and fullStationList and stationList? Do any of these colection have any NULL item in them.?

Comment: One possibility is that fullStationList being accessed elsewhere, and the elements of it (which are references of items on stationList) are made NULL..

Comment: @bit _loadedStations & fullStationList both have 1155 items while (due to the filtering) stationList has 1150. I had wondered about the list being accessed elsewhere but can't see where that would occur

Comment: Problem 'solved' but I'm still confused as to why it was a problem in the first place. Thanks for all your input

Comment: 2018 and still experiencing this issue! Was at a loss until I found your question and "solution."

Comment: I just ran into this in a regular C# .NET project, so it's not specific to Xamarin. Changing the variable name of one of the two loop variables with the same name fixed it for me, too.

Answer (score 3):

It seems like this has something to do with the way Xamarin works , changing var name solves the issue

```
 foreach(var stationItem in stationList)
 {

     // Breakpoint on next line shows station to be null..!
     if(stationItem.ClusterId != Guid.Empty)
     {
         // Code in here
     }
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried it in this way and it works:

```
internal class CStation
{
    private Guid _clusterId;

    public CStation()
    {

        _clusterId = Guid.NewGuid(); 
    }

    public Guid StationName
    {
        get { return _clusterId; }
    }
}

private voit TestList()
{

    List<CStation> stationList = new List<CStation>();
    CStation test1 = new CStation();
    CStation test2 = new CStation();
    CStation test3 = new CStation();
    stationList.Add(test1);
    stationList.Add(test2);
    stationList.Add(test3);

    foreach (var station in stationList)
    {

        // Breakpoint on next line shows station to be null..!
        if (station == null )
        {
            throw new  ArgumentNullException();
        }
    }
}
```

I think you didnt instantiate the Guid.
I did it in the constructor of Station -> `_clusterId = Guid.NewGuid();`

Comment: But as OP mentioned `station is null` not `station.StationName is null`, besides that it should probably be `void` not `voit` on `TestList()`

Comment: @DrCopyPaste is correct - the station itself is null

Comment: To clarify, the ClusterId is present in the items within the List and contain actual GUIDs or Guid.Empty (all 0's)

Comment: @DilbertDave: I changed the code to check if station is null. It isnt. the ArgumentNullException does not get thrown. Have you checked if `var stationList = fullStationList.Where(x => mapBounds.Contains(new LatLng(x.Latitude, x.Longitude))).ToList();` returns a valid list?

Comment: @ck84vi That's how it should work for sure but for some reason despite stationList being populated (yes, I have checked) the resulting iterations have a null station.